# 100% layout with min/max sizes which doesn't overflow

Tags: javascript, html

I have two layout elements lets say one is 33%, the other 66%. They both use 100% of my screen size (So it is dependent on browser window). The smaller element also has a min-size property, so it cant fall below 250px;

Now if the layout is at least 757px large (so the size where the min property doesn't apply) everything looks fine. If the layout falls below the 757px the second element starts to overflow since it still takes the 66%, so the sum of both layouts exceeds the 100%.

I made some graphics to show the behavior:

Layout 1000px not overflowing:[image: Layout 1000px not overflowing]

Layout 500px overflowing[image: Layout 500px overflowing]

Is there a solution to prevent the overflow (not overflow: hidden) so the second element takes only the remaining space when the first element reaches it's min width.
Also JavaScript shouldn't be used excessive!

Regards, Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is actually pretty easy and requires a very minimal amount of code:

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
...
</div>
<div class="content">
...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar{ 
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.content { 
    overflow: hidden; /* Ensures that your content will not overlap the sidebar */
}
```

You can view the live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7A4Tj/

Edit:

If you're trying to achieve a site layout that has equal-height background images for the sidebar and content, all you need to do is wrap both those elements in a containing div and use the [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique.

Comment: looks nice but I guees it will take some time till I squeeze this into my page...

Comment: What do you mean? Is there anything you need clarification on?

Comment: lets ust say I'm not a html developer/designer/.... so just adding a <p> element to the top of the label is a certian challenge for me ;)

Comment: If you post your site/source we can show you how to build around it if you are stuck.

Comment: how can I prefent from going into the next line when the 250px are reached?

Comment: Set a min-width for your container.

Comment: Sure, just change `float: left` to `float: right` and leave the HTML as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following for the second widget:

```
position: fixed;
right: 0;
```

Comment: can you make an example? It's a little less for me to know what you mean :/

Comment: According to your graphics, Widget 2's style only has height:66%. Include these two lines in Widget 2's style.

Answer (score 0):

Here´s my five cents

min-width on both divs
and a wrapper that also has min-width, plus both of the divs having percentage width

[JS fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/qZmNX/4/)

PS seems to be working fine in IE8

PPS Also do check out @media queries if you want to have conditional CSS rules on different window sizes, might be helpful. Will run on browsers supporting CSS3: [CSS Media queries at CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/)